# local files missing from docker-machine container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

So I have a simple containerised django project, with another container for sass css compilation.

I use docker-compose with a docker-machine, but when I fire it up, the web container doesn't have any of my local files (manage.py etc) in, so it dies with a `file not found: manage.py` error.

Let me explain more:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  ports:
    - "8001:5000"
sass:
  image: ubuntudesign/sass
  command: sass --debug-info --watch /app/static/css -E "UTF-8"
  volumes:
    - .:/app
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Install apt dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip git bzr libpq-dev pkg-config

FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Install apt dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip git bzr libpq-dev pkg-config

# Pip requirements files
COPY requirements /requirements

# Install pip requirements
RUN pip install -r /requirements/dev.txt

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

And a standard django project in the local directory:

```
$ ls 
docker-compose.yml Dockerfile manage.py README.md static templates webapp
```

And here's the error as isolated as I can make it:

> `$ docker-compose run web python`
>
> `can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Which is true:

> `$ docker-compose run web ls`
>
> `static`

I think this is a problem with working with remote `docker-machine`s, I've tried to follow the [simple django tutorial](http://docs.docker.com/compose/django/), and I reckon local file sharing works differently.

What works differently when using docker-machine?

Comment: Would you mind including an edit with the "end result" Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml files?

Comment: I no longer have that config, sorry, but it was very simple: Only do the copy on one unit (I used the web unit), then all other units do volume_from: web

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker volumes mount files from the *host* into the container.

So in this case, you've mounted the current directory of whatever host docker-machine is pointing to into the container. Unless you have some funky VM crossmounting going on (like boot2docker does), this isn't going to match the directories on the machine you're running on.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! So it's local from the point of view of my docker-machine. Do you know the best way to do this? I'd like to push my django app to a docker-machine-controlled container. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah - put the code in the container :) Or edit files on the remote host.

Comment: I've updated the Q with the full Dockerfile, isn't that what the COPY (also ADD) directives do? I've tried both! Thanks :-)

Comment: Yeah, that should work; just remove the volume statement now (it will be mounting an empty dir over the top of the code).

Comment: Hey, that works! removing both instances of the volume mounting from the yml file did the trick! However, now my sass container doesn't have access to the files, and so doesn't compile them. `No such file or directory - /app/static/css`
Can two containers access the same local files?

Comment: Yeah, see also --volumes-from and data containers https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Comment: Yeah! I fixed it all up nicely with `volumes_from`, thank you!